# Sort NSAarray with custom objects with dates

Tags: objective-c, ios

i have an NSArray which contains custom objects, the objects have an NSString property, like this :

```
@interface Reservation : NSObject{

    int _id;    
    NSString *dateAndHour;
    ....
}
```

example :

```
Reservation *reserv = [Reservation alloc]init];
          reserrv._id=1;
          reservation.dateAndHour =@"03/09/1983 07:30 PM";
```

I have an NSArray which contains objects Reservation, now i would like to sort my array with the field dateAndHour, how i can do this please.
thanks for your aswer

Comment: i am sorry, i have not understand your comment ?

Comment: "Witch" refers to a person who practices witchcraft. "Which" is the word you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert that date string into an `NSDate` and then you can just use a `sortDescriptor`

```
NSSortDescriptor *dateSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dateSort];

reservations = [reservations sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```